# MS word layout issue: Text area covers only half its area

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, page-layout-view

**In short**: I would like to be able to get the text to expand to the whole width of the window (the red rectangle on the picture) instead of being stuck to only half the window. I would also like to keep the Web layout.

**In details:**
My friend sent me several documents and among those documents, there is one that has a strange layout that I can't manage to change. My friend doesn't know what happened to this file, nor do I. All the others Word documents he sent me don't have this problem and my other word files also don't have this problem. Setting the view to draft is better, but still the text doesn't expand to the entire window.

If I change the zoom, the number in the ruler change but the text still doesn't expand to the entire window.

If I double click on the ruler, the page setup options all look alike the ones I have on my others word documents, so the problem doesn't seem to come from there.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Does it look closer to what you want when you copy\paste it into notepad? Hard to tell by the picture but it looks to be a listing. If so, then just paste from notepad into the document.

Comment: Thanks krowe for your help! I've change the screenshot because it was misleading. Now there is a plain text and still the text doesn't expand to the red rectangle.

Comment: @krowe It was a comment, simply hiding it or deleting it did the trick. Since you helped me, if you write this in an answer, I will accept it (and delete this comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue when I received a friend document and it only shows 2/3 page with contents. I tried to modify the page setting (margin, border, page size, etc), none of them works. Finally I came to find there was my friend's comment there. By deleting the comment, it is back to normal. So hope this can help you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can often fix this type of layout problem by pasting into a plain text editor first and then copying that unformatted text into word (or using the "Keep text only button" when you paste into word). In this particular case, it looks like your text is in a 1x1 table (which is why even in web layout you have a max page size).

Comment: great now say where to go to remove the stupid invisible table

Comment: I will not help you anymore until this post has at least +2 votes. You figure out how to do that and I'll explain how to solve your issue.